# Multiple arrays in nusoap output

Tags: soap, nusoap, complextype

This is what I have:

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType('ResultObject',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(
        'Result' => array('name' => 'Result', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
        'Action' => array('name' => 'Action', 'type' => 'xsd:string')
    )
);
```

And in `register` nusoap function output param is as below:

```
array('ResultObject' => 'tns:ResultObject')  // output parameters
```

The question I have is that result is now array of 3 elements NOT `xsd:string`:

- Continue
- End
- AbortReason

Each one of the above has `address`(xsd:anyURI), `code`(xsd:int). How to implement this structure as a complexType?

---

**EDIT:**

Here you can see that Abort Reason has `Reason` part type, and reason has its own structure.
[image]

The reason structure has `code`, `description` fields.
[image]

I want to implement this structure for the output with addComplexType

Comment: You need to post the relevant portions of your WSDL file along with the web service you are trying to access.  From your username, it sounds like you are using PHP.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen could see the `EDIT` part?